# Как создать слабосвязанную связь

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

Доброго времени суток уважаемые форумчане. Делаю учебный проект и столкнулся со следующим вопросом.
Проект состоит из двух частей Domain и UI. 
В Domaine создал интерфейсы, их реализацию и классы:

```
public interface IDbRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Article> Article { get; }
    }

 public class EFRepository:IDbRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context= new ApplicationDbContext();

        public IQueryable<Article> Article
        {
            get { return _context.Articles; }
        }
    }

//данные классы перенес из UI
namespace Domain.FF
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

В UI объявил ninject

```
private void AddBindings()
        {
            // конфигурирование контейнера
            ninjectKernel.Bind<IDbRepository>().To<EFRepository>();
        }
```

И при вот такой вот реализации контроллера я вижу класс Article

```
private IDbRepository _repository;
public ХХController(IDbRepository reposit)
        {
            this._repository = reposit;
        }
```

Вроде как все норм работает, но возникает вопрос как соблюсти принцип слабосвязанности в

```
AccountController

    public class AccountController : Controller
        {
            public AccountController()
                : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
            {
            }
```

Куда что и как добавить? а то пока получается в случае если объявлять в using пространство имен Domain.FF.

За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В asp.net mvc есть такая вещь, как DependencyResolver. Если вы ставили ninject.Mvc, то должно заработать. Примерно так:

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserStore>();
```

[Здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176007/) можете почитать

Comment: Veikedo
Спасибо большое. Статья немного помогла). Правда сделал фиг пойми как и в итоге не знаю правильно это в плане шаблона или нет, но работает:).

Comment: По паттерну самому можете почитать http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2013/01/blog-post.html

И книга ещё есть, Dependency Injection in .net

Вообще ioc не самоцель, исходите из того, как вам удобнее будет

Comment: Да просто только разбираюсь во всем этом программирвоанию. Читаю книгу Фримена по MVC и пробую что-то свое писать). Так там рекомендовано такое разделение....Спасибо за ссылки) буду изучать)